# Add hyperlink to some cells in syncfusion treegrid - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, syncfusion

I want to add a link to EJ TreeGrid and I want pass the column's on href.

```
col.Field("NoteID")
                      .HeaderText("View")
                      .Width(80)
                      .TextAlign(TextAlign.Right)
                      .IsTemplateColumn(true)
                      .Template("<a href='" + @Url.Action("GetNoteID", "Notes") + "/" + "/{NoteID}' target='_blank'>View Broker Note</a>")                     
                      .Add();
```

How can I pass the pass NoteID on {NoteID} in the href link?

I tried:

```
.ClientSideEvents(eve =>
                  {
                     eve.QueryCellInfo("querycellinfo");
                  })`

`function querycellinfo(args) {
        if (args.column.field === "NoteID" && args.cellValue != null) {
            $(args.cellElement).find(".linkbtn").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: @Url.Action("GetNoteID", "Notes") + "/" + args.cellValue,
                    data: args.data,
                    dataType: "json"
                });
            })
        }
    }
```

but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address your requirement, we have provided a sample where we used template in the column to provide a hyperlink and passed the taskname value using double curly braces with Colon {{: }}, you can find the code snippet and sample Link below

Code Snippet:

/*index.cshtml*/

.Columns(co =>

```
{

 co.Field("TaskName").HeaderText("Task Name").EditType(TreeGridEditingType.String).Template("<a href='" + @Url.Action("GetNoteID", "Notes") + "/" + "/{{:TaskName}}' target='_blank'>View Broker Note</a>").IsTemplateColumn(true).Add();
```

}

Sample Link : https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/TestSample1393020514

UG LINK : https://help.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/treegrid/columns#column-template

Regards,

Udhayakumar